# Getting to work Hostapd with RTL8192CU chipset on IPFire

Tags: linux, wifi, raspberry-pi, hostapd

I've got IP Fire set up on my RPi and despite the RTL8192CU chipset working with a bit of tweaking from a guide I found, it doesn't seem to work with hostapd on IPFire.

The TP-Link USB dongle flashes when IPFire boots but Hostapd tells me "Interface Green0: is no wireless device".

I've Googled around but not much luck in finding a fix for it.